# Get "now playing" in iTunes Radio and other third party music app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

Are there any ways to get "now playing" in iTunes Radio.
For "Music" App, I use following code to get now playing info.
(Title, for example)

```
  [[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]
```

But when user is listening to iTunes Radio, the code above returns (NULL).

I want to know are there any ways to get now playing info in iTunes Radio and third party music apps.